# How does the mundane infusion work?

Tags: dark-souls-2

How does the mundane infusion affect your weapons effectiveness?

I mean the Mundane Stone description reads:

> "An altered state of titanite. Use to imbue weapons with power of the
>   mundane. Cannot be used on shields.
>
> People do not look favorably on the banal, but sometimes even the most mundane of objects can cast things in a most pleasant light."

And that gives me absolutely no insight on what it does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mundane gives massive scaling depending on your *lowest stat*. If your lowest stat is at 20, Mundane gives physical scaling at 170, which is amazing.

For example, if you have 20s in your stats across the board except for INT, which you left at 5, Mundane will scale off INT and have +80 physical scaling. As you increase INT, the damage scaling will increase. Once INT hits 21, it's no longer the lowest stat as the others are at 20. At this point, Mundane will stay scaled to 170 since your lowest stat is at 20.

According to the [Dark Souls 2 wikidot](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/old-mundane-stone), the exact mundane scaling goes as follows:

[image]

Comment: Could I get it scale atunement and wield like a brazillion pyromancy spells?  Or is that just a pipedream?  I am guessing that this would let me be a pretty good spellcaster in spite of being a physical build right?  And when you say scaling, does it augment the scaling factor that the weapon already has?

Comment: It will scale off whatever stat is *lowest*. So, you can raise Attunement as high as you want, but it won't scale off Attunement unless it's your lowest stat. Therefore, you won't have "a brazillion" Pyromancy spells and still have it scale to Attunement, as Attunement will likely not be your lowest stat at that point.

Comment: In other words, if you have a balanced character, mundane is a viable option. If you are focused on a particular stat, you won't see much of a benefit?

Comment: @Dom That's exactly right.

Comment: is the Scaling Bonus visible anywere? or Do I have just to assume it is there?